# Eliminate units when using quantities for Python

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

I'm using the great [quantities](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/quantities) package for Python. I would like to know how I can get at just the numerical value of the quantity, without the unit.

I.e., if I have

```
E = 5.3*quantities.joule
```

I would like to get at just the 5.3. I know I can simply divide by the "undesired" unit, but hoping there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`E.item()` seems to be what you want, if you want a Python float. `E.magnitude`, offered by tzaman, is a 0-dimensional NumPy array with the value, if you'd prefer that.

The documentation for `quantities` doesn't seem to have a very good API reference.

Comment: If your quantity is a list (or a numpy array), you need `magnitude` instead of `item()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `E.magnitude` gets you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import quantities
>>> E=5.3*quantities.joule
>>> E.item()
5.3
```