# Getting rid of units in astropy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, astropy

I have a large `(262615,3)` array of values that all have units attached to them. Specifically originating from this function:

```
def coordconvert(data):
    from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
    from astropy import units as u
    import numpy as np 

    R   = data[:,0]
    ra  = data[:,1]
    dec = data[:,2]

    c = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree,dec=dec*u.degree,distance=R*u.mpc)
    outdata = c.cartesian.xyz

    return outdata
```

I would like for this array to be unit less so I can easily write it into a textfile. 
Before anyone links the Stack Exchange [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403415/eliminate-units-when-using-quantities-for-python) asking something similar, I have tried using .magnitude and it doesn't work. Also I would like to add, due to the nature of my array I would prefer the most efficient possible way of doing so, if possible.

A sample of data:

```
 <Quantity -473.698 mpc> <Quantity -38.3794 mpc> <Quantity -1832.23 mpc>
 <Quantity -2269.57 mpc> <Quantity -842.855 mpc> <Quantity -2445.88 mpc>
```

Comment: Instead of the function (that is irrelevant to the question), please include a sample of your data, expected output, and what exactly you attempted to get that output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `c.cartesian.xyz` is a Quantity object. It has a `unit` attribute and a `value` attribute.

The `value` attribute is a Numpy array and I think is what you want.

Example:

```
>>> from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
>>> c = SkyCoord(10, 20, unit='deg')
>>> c.cartesian.xyz
<Quantity [0.92541658, 0.16317591, 0.34202014]>
>>> c.cartesian.xyz.value
array([0.92541658, 0.16317591, 0.34202014])
>>> type(c.cartesian.xyz.value)
numpy.ndarray
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `value` attribute, but need to make sure that you specify the part and unit of the coordinate that you are interested in, e.g. the R.A. value:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u

c = SkyCoord(ra=[0., 1., 100.] *u.degree,dec=[1., 2., -3.]*u.degree)

c.ra

>> <SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
>> [(   0.,  1.), (   1.,  2.), ( 100., -3.)]>

c.ra.value
>> array([   0.,    1.,  100.])
```

You can also get units for different formats, e.g. hours/radians/arcmin for angles

```
c.ra.arcmin
>> array([    0.,    60.,  6000.])
```

Comment: can i do c.values and would the whole array lose all units?

Comment: I just looked it up and couldn't find a way to do this, so you'll have to do it for each axis (R.A., Dec., distance) of your coordinate array. I'd be happy to be proven wrong, though!