# changing astropy SkyCoord object into float

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I am working with the astropy function pixel_to_SkyCoords which takes 2 1D arrays of coordinates, a wcs transform system (.fits HDU), and returns an object of the SkyCoord class that contains the equivalent sky coordinates.
Since I have many pixel coordinates, I am iterating through a for loop:

```
transform_file = ap.io.fits.open('/home/jryan/astrometry_tests/75mm_field_new-image_3rd.fits')
transform = ap.wcs.WCS(transform_file[0].header, naxis=2)

sky_pts = []
for star in range(num_objects):
    sky_coords = ap.wcs.utils.pixel_to_skycoord(x[star],y[star], transform) 
    sky_pts.append(sky_coords)
```

The problem is that when the sky_coords variable is appended to sky_pts, it is not appending the values of the coordinates, but rather the SkyCoord object. I want the values themselves so I can put them into a Dataframe. How can I convert this object to a float to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: SkyCoord has a `to_string` method https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.html

Comment: this appears to make no difference @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: Until I have a chance to give a proper answer, see if this helps any: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659120/982257 Also don't use a for loop. Try just `pixel_to_skycoord(x, y, transform)`